# Vowel is to diphthong as consonant is to?

Tags: single-word-requests, consonants, diphthongs

While reading about diphthongs in a different question today, I noticed that while the word "diphthong" doesn't seem to contain any actual diphthongs, it does contain 3 sets of consonant groupings.

When I was younger, I used to think consonant groupings actually were called diphthongs. I know now that I was mistaken, but I do wonder - **is there a single word that describes consonant groupings?**

After doing some searching on Google, Wikipedia and this site, I'm unable to find a definitive answer besides "consonant cluster" or "consecutive consonant". Those terms may be the only accurate ones available, but I would be mildly disappointed.

Comment: They are also known as blends, which would satisfy your single word criteria, but consonant cluster seems like the term for them...

Comment: Are you talking about sounds, or letters? Do you mean things like [affricates and coarticulated consonants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Affricates_and_double_articulated_consonants)?

Comment: Just to echo @tchrist, your question is ambiguous. Your comment about 'diphthong' suggests you're interested in digraphs, your comparison to diphthongs suggests you're interested in either coarticulated consonants, or phonemes which consist of a sequence of two consonantal targets (affricates and a few other odds and ends). Answering would be easier if you told us which it is.

Comment: @Gaston; choster read my intentions well, as did you. I was looking for "digraphs". However, the list you just put in your comments made for some very interesting reading. Linguistics is interesting to me but I have a lot to learn about it.

Comment: OK well, in addition to digraphs there are trigraphs and tetragraphs: groups of 3 or 4 letters used to represent a single phoneme.

Comment: A diphthong is the kind of sandal that goofy kid wore when I was in the 3rd grade.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The directly analogous term is indeed **[consonant cluster](http://www.sil.org/lingualinks/literacy/referencematerials/glossaryofliteracyterms/whatisaconsonantcluster.htm)**, a combination of consonant sounds that appear together.

It is possible that you are thinking of a **[digraph](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/digraph)**, which is two characters representing a *single* sound, rather than a blending of adjacent sounds as with a diphthong or consonant cluster. For example, the *ch* in *church* or the *sh* in *hashish* are digraphs.

Comment: In fact, the "ch" of "church" is in a way composed of two sounds, in that it is an affricate: it starts with a stop consonant sound [t], and releases into a fricative consonant sound [ʃ].

Comment: If consonant clusters are like diphthongs, then what compares to vowel clusters?

Comment: @GregLee , Choster "If consonant clusters are like diphthongs, then what compares to vowel clusters?" <-- Exactly so. The analagous term to diphthong is presumably *affricate*.

Comment: But an affricate is only a stop plus a fricative; there are many other ways consonants can occur together, e.g. at the start of words two stops together (common in Greek), or a stop plus a nasal (in many Germanic languages), or syllables with syllabic /r/, /l/, /n/, /m/. There are also consonants with two places of articulation, which could be considered as two consonants together (English labial-velar /w/ for instance).

Comment: @StuartF The point is that diphtongs represent a single phoneme, in other words a single vowel that changes in quality. Two consonants together is just a sequence of two consonants. An affricate is a single consonant that changes manner half way through.

Answer (score 2):

The technical term is simply "consonant cluster" or "consonant blend". As spoken, they are part of the general class of "phonemes" (especially "digraphs", groups that indicate a non-transitive mouth position, such as "th").

Many phonetic alphabets have specific characters for phonemes that we use consonant clusters for; for instance, the Greek "theta" is a single character that Romanizes to "th". Norse runic lanuages had the "thorn" character, with much the same purpose. The Russian character ш is pronounced similarly to "sh" as in "show". By contrast, the Japanese alphabet is made up primarily of consonant-vowel pairs, and the only "consonant clusters" seen in Romanized spellings involve "n", which is the only consonant sound that exists unpaired in gana/kana (it also exists paired).

Comment: No, things like *th* require only one IPA character.  They are not two different consonant sounds.

Comment: Where exactly did I say different? Please remove the downvote.

Comment: In English, 'th' is a digraph and not a consonant cluster. In English, 'th' is phonemically a single consonant, even though we spell it with two letters. I believe 'ts' in Japanese is a better example for the single phoneme–consonant cluster dichotomy.

Comment: Actually the only occurrence of the sound "ts" is in the single character "tsu"; neither "t" nor "s" sounds exist by themselves. Where you might hear "ts" (or other consonants) pronounced without a trailing vowel is in an unstressed syllable at the end of a word ending in "u"; the "u" of such a syllable is whispered or simply dropped.

Comment: I think your answer might not have received a downvote if you had done a better job of clarifying when you mean consonant *sound* versus consonant *letter*.

Comment: I downvoted for the reason nohat gives above. In particular, the sentence "Many phonetic alphabets have specific characters for phonemes that we use consonant clusters for" suggests (wrongly, in my view) that it is correct to refer to the "th" in words like "ether" as a "consonant cluster".

Answer (score 0):

There actually are things like consonant diphthongs that occur, though most people aren't aware of them. The sound /j/ is actually a combination of the sounds /d/ and /zh/. The sound /ch/ is a combination of /t/ and /sh/. Both of these are shown this way when they are written in IPA. The letter 'x' is a combination of /k/ and /s/. Qu is a combination of /k/ and /w/. And as was mentioned above, the consonant diphthong /t/-/s/ also comes up in words like tsunami, mozzarella, and pizza.

Comment: That's interesting! But what are they called?

Comment: Regarding your IPA: Please do not use slash brackets for non-IPA phonetic transcriptions, especially since /j/ means the "y" sound in "Yankee". The symbols you need are, in order, and provided for your copy-pasting needs: /dʒ/, /d/, /ʒ/, /tʃ/, /t/, /ʃ/, /k/, /s/, /k/, /w/, and /ts/ (for the pair at the end - no intermediate characters are needed). If you feel the need to use "j", use quotes and a description like 'the "j" sound in "Juliett"'.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a note about part of one kind of consonant group:

Components of a subset of the consonant clusters mentioned in other answers are **liquid consonants**, like /l/ in *cluster* and /r/ in *crocodile*:

> Liquid consonants are more prone to be part of consonant clusters and of the syllable nucleus. Their third formants are generally non-predictable based on the first two formants. Another important feature is their complex articulation, which makes them a hard consonant class to study with precision and the last consonants to be produced by children during their phonological development. They are also more likely to undergo certain types of phonological changes such as assimilation, dissimilation and metathesis.
>
> Most languages have at least one liquid in their phonemic inventory. English has two, /l/ and /ɹ/. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_consonant))